# recording streaming audio on iphone/ipod touch

Tags: objective-c, audio-recording

This application currently plays audio from onine stations.

Basically it has 2 main features:
Play: 
On click of a station name or the play button, the fm station starts playing.

Record : 
On click of the record link, the recorders starts recording. Clicking it again, stops and replays the recorded audio.

### The problem

1. The streaming recording is not recording clearly.
   The current recorder using AVAudioRecorder though records the audio, the sound is noisy.
   Could it be because the streaming audio uses audioQueue while the recorder used is AVAudioRecorder which also records from microphone.We want to record only the streaming content.

Note: The AVAudioRecorder when used for voice recording is clear, but not good with recording streaming audio content.

For playing streaming audio, i used code from Mr. Matt Gallagher link is 
[here](http://cocoawithlove.com/2008/09/streaming-and-playing-live-mp3-stream.html)

Can you please suggest a better way to record streaming audio.
Is there an existing API like AVAudioRecorder or am I doing something wrong ?

Comment: hi, did you get the solution? I am also having similar problem

Comment: No not yet. still trying to figure it out.

Comment: did u get any solution..  i got one app form appstore iskysoft audio recorder only streming content. its fine.. i need smae like that

Comment: did you find a solution to this?

Answer (score 0):

Please Look at this Framework. It provide data for recording while recording Streaming Kit [Streaming Kit](https://github.com/tumtumtum/StreamingKit)

Play an MP3 over HTTP

```
STKAudioPlayer* audioPlayer = [[STKAudioPlayer alloc] init];

[audioPlayer play:@"http://www.abstractpath.com/files/audiosamples/sample.mp3"];
```

And append its data to NSMutabledata to play offline by using this delegate.

Intercept PCM data just before its played

```
 [audioPlayer appendFrameFilterWithName:@"MyCustomFilter" block:^(UInt32 channelsPerFrame, UInt32 bytesPerFrame, UInt32 frameCount, void* frames)
   {
   ...
   }];
```

Comment: do you know how I can use the frames being returned in the appendFrameFilterWithName to create the mp3 file of the recording?